# How do you use an input as a variable name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, input

I have this dict:

```
exercise_name = {
            "sets": 3,
            "reps": 12,
            "weight": 100
}
```

I know I can get a user input with:

```
exercise_name = input("Insert Exercise Name: ")
```

But how can I assign my dictionary directly to the input?
Something like:

```
input("Insert Exercise Name: ") = {
    "sets": 3,
    "reps": 12,
    "weight": 100
}
```

I'd also like to know how to do it with lists, sets, etc.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: @BenjaminBreton I want the user to give an input. Then, I want to create a dictionary and store it in a variable equal to the input. Say, for example, the user types "squat". I want squat = {}. If the user types "bench", I want bench = {}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't**.

How would you know in your program to address that dictionay anyhow? If the user "customizes" the variables name?  This sounds like an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You could store the user input in a dict as well:

```
sillyDict = { input("Insert name") : { "sets": 3, "reps": 12, "weight": 100}}
```

but to what purpose - how are you going to *use* it?  You would need to know about the given name or iterate over the whole dict if you want to do anything with it.

---

It looks as if what you really need are [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) and [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
class Exercise: 
    """Capsules data for one exercise. sets/reps/weigh have defaults."""

    def __init__(self, name, sets = 3, reps = 12, weight = 100):
        """'name'd exercise with sets/reps/weight - using defaults:
        sets = 3, reps = 12, weight = 100"""
        self.name = name
        self.sets = sets
        self.reps = reps
        self.weight = weight

    def __str__(self):
         """Friendly representation of this exercise"""
         return f"{self.name}: {self.sets} sets of {self.reps} reps with {self.weight} kg"

    def __repr__(self):
         return str(self) 

# create a plan            
plan = [ Exercise("Squats"), Exercise("BenchPress",3,5,180), Exercise("Pullups",5,22,10)]

# add one by user input (fragile) - no int-validation
plan.append( Exercise(input("What to do? "), 
                      int(input("Sets: ")), 
                      int(input("Reps: ")), 
                      int(input("Weight: "))))

for exer in plan:
    print(exer)

print(plan)
```

Output:

```
What to do? Burpies
Sets: 5
Reps: 15
Weight: 0

Squats: 3 sets of 12 reps with 100 kg       # uses the default values
BenchPress: 3 sets of 5 reps with 180 kg
Pullups: 5 sets of 22 reps with 10 kg
Burpies: 5 sets of 15 reps with 0 kg

[Squats: 3 sets of 12 reps with 100 kg, BenchPress: 3 sets of 5 reps with 180 kg, 
 Pullups: 5 sets of 22 reps with 10 kg, Burpies: 5 sets of 15 reps with 0 kg]
```

Comment: I thought about using classes and lists, but I'm a newbie that's still figuring out OOP. But yeah this seems like the best option. And I guess there's no better way to learn than doing. Thanks!